# How can I style my Category Heading in Wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to style this

```
<?php 
single_cat_title('Category:');
?>
```

of my archive.php file.

How should I proceed?

Comment: define a `singl_cat_line` function that does your styling. Or, please, specify what you actually want to do so we can give a meaningful answer.

Comment: Thanks, Federico for your reply. As the default theme that I am using didn't have the category title, thus I added this code in the PHP file and I want to individually style this function. It's looking like this [screenshot](https://snag.gy/prqcZJ.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it in a `div` with some class:

```
<div class="category-heading">
    <?php 
        single_cat_title('Category:');
    ?>
</div>
```

and then style with CSS:

```
.category-heading {
     background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Petya for your kind response. I will try it for sure and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it to div with class

```
<div class="category">
<?php 
single_cat_title('Category:');
?>
</div>
```

As it is in this page in paragraph - [Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_cat_title/#user-contributed-notes)

Comment: Thanks, @David for providing me with the solution. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Thanks too :) You can mark, or vote my answer if it was helpful.